# Can't map roles to groups using ibm-application-bnd.xml

Tags: websphere, jaas, user-roles

I'm trying to map user groups using ibm-application-bnd.xml. Put it into META-INF folder. On try to access secure page get next message:

```
[08.05.15 17:42:21:242 MSK] 00000084 WebCollaborat A   SECJ0129E: ... GET в null:/loginmodule/date/, Authorization failed, Not granted any of the required roles: user-role
```

When I try configure it with ibm console it works. All configuration WAS writes into ibm-application-bnd.xmi instead of ibm-application-bnd.xml.

What do I wrong?
Using Websphere AS 8.5.5 with Java 1.6

ibm-application-bnd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/dxml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
      xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.2">
      <security-role name="user-role">
            <group name="user-group" />
      </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
      <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <security-constraint>
            <display-name>Constraint</display-name>
            <web-resource-collection>
                  <web-resource-name>secrets</web-resource-name>
                  <description />
                  <url-pattern>/date/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                  <role-name>user-role</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>

      <security-role>
            <role-name>user-role</role-name>
      </security-role>

      <servlet>
            <servlet-name>date</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>ru.servlet.TimeServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>date</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/date/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server uses XML for EE 5+ only, and that decision is made on a per-deployment descriptor basis.  If ibm-application-bnd.xmi is being used, then I suspect your application.xml has version="1.4" or lower, so try again after updating to an EE 5 XML header (remove doctype, add xmlns, add xmlns:xsi, add xsi:schemaLocation, update version attribute).

Comment: You saved my day. Changed the version in the POM of the maven-ear-plugin to 6 did the trick. See answer

Answer (score 4):

I had to change the version in my ear POM maven-ear-plugin. Because default it generates a 1.3 application.xml so the Websphere server only expect a ibm-application-bnd.xmi file and not a ibm-application-bnd.xml file

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <version>6</version>
    <security>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>manager</role-name>
        </security-role>
    </security>
    <modules>
        <webModule>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-war</artifactId>
            <contextRoot>/my-app</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
```

Thanks to bkail

Comment: This was indeed the cause of the problem for me.  It was helpful to checking the application.xml generated in the ear project's target directory.  In passing I also learned you can export the ear via the admin console, which if you applied the security role manually, will show you the bnd.xml or .xmi file that it is using.