# Websphere 8.5.5 - shared session context not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, httpsession

I am moving an enterprise application that contains 2 web modules.  In the ibm-application-ext.xmi I have  so the two web modules can use the same session.  In WebSphere 6.1 this works just fine but in WebSphere 8.5.5 it is not working.  Does anyone know if shared session context still truly works in 8.5.5.  The documentation says it has been deprecated but still available.  We do have plans to merge the two web modules into one but that will not occur for awhile.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question.
[Can't map roles to groups using ibm-application-bnd.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126747/cant-map-roles-to-groups-using-ibm-application-bnd-xml/33918120#comment60865304_33918120)

With a Java EE application.xml version newer than "1.4" (e.g., "5" or "6") the conventions changed from .xmi files to .xml files of the same name.  The schema is a bit different than the original .xmi files so you will unfortunately need to port your existing customizations into the new format.